# Redis `SCAN`: how to maintain a balance between newcomming keys that might match and ensure eventual result in a reasonable time?

Tags: redis

I am not that familiar with `Redis`. At the moment I am designing some realtime service and I'd like to rely on it. I expect ~10000-50000 keys per minute to be `SET` with some reasonable `EX` and match over them using `SCAN` rarely enough not to bother with performance bottlenecks.

The thing I doubt is "in/out rate" and possible overflooding with keys that might match some `SCAN` query and thus it never terminates (i.e. always replies with latest cursor position and forces you to continue; that could happen easily if one consumes `x items per second` and there are `x + y items per second coming in` with `y > 0`).

Obviously, I could set desired `SCAN` size long enough; but I wonder if there exists a better solution or does `Redis` itself guarantees that `SCAN` will grow size automatically in such a case?

Comment: What are you using repeated scan for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First some context, **solution at the end**:

From [SCAN command > Guarantee of termination](https://redis.io/commands/scan#guarantee-of-termination)

> The SCAN algorithm is guaranteed to terminate only if the size of the
>   iterated collection remains bounded to a given maximum size, otherwise
>   iterating a collection that always grows may result into SCAN to never
>   terminate a full iteration.
>
> This is easy to see intuitively: if the collection grows there is more
>   and more work to do in order to visit all the possible elements, and
>   the ability to terminate the iteration depends on the number of calls
>   to SCAN and its COUNT option value compared with the rate at which the
>   collection grows.

But in [The COUNT option](https://redis.io/commands/scan#the-count-option) it says:

> Important: there is no need to use the same COUNT value for every
>   iteration. The caller is free to change the count from one iteration
>   to the other as required, as long as the cursor passed in the next
>   call is the one obtained in the previous call to the command.

Important to keep in mind, from [Scan guarantees](https://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-guarantees):

> - A given element may be returned multiple times. It is up to the
>     application to handle the case of duplicated elements, for example
>     only using the returned elements in order to perform operations that
>     are safe when re-applied multiple times.
> - Elements that were not
>     constantly present in the collection during a full iteration, may be
>     returned or not: it is undefined.

The key to a solution is in the cursor itself. See [Making sense of Redis’ SCAN cursor](https://engineering.q42.nl/redis-scan-cursor/). **It is possible to deduce the percent of progress of your scan because the cursor is really the bits-reversed of an index to the table size.**

Using `DBSIZE` or `INFO keyspace` command you can get how many keys you have at any time:

```
> DBSIZE
(integer) 200032
> info keyspace
# Keyspace
db0:keys=200032,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Another source of information is the undocumented `DEBUG htstats index`, just to get a feeling:

```
> DEBUG htstats 0
[Dictionary HT]
Hash table 0 stats (main hash table):
 table size: 262144
 number of elements: 200032
 different slots: 139805
 max chain length: 8
 avg chain length (counted): 1.43
 avg chain length (computed): 1.43
 Chain length distribution:
   0: 122339 (46.67%)
   1: 93163 (35.54%)
   2: 35502 (13.54%)
   3: 9071 (3.46%)
   4: 1754 (0.67%)
   5: 264 (0.10%)
   6: 43 (0.02%)
   7: 6 (0.00%)
   8: 2 (0.00%)
[Expires HT]
No stats available for empty dictionaries
```

The table size is the power of 2 following your number of keys:
Keys: 200032  =>  Table size: 262144

### The solution:

We will calculate a desired `COUNT` argument for every scan.

Say you will be calling SCAN with a frequency (`F` in Hz) of 10 Hz (every 100 ms) and you want it done in 5 seconds (`T` in s). So you want this finished in `N = F*T` calls, `N = 50` in this example.

Before your first scan, you know your current progress is 0, so your remaining percent is `RP = 1` (100%).

Before every `SCAN` call (or every given number of calls that you want to adjust your COUNT if you want to save the Round Trip Time (RTT) of a `DBSIZE` call), you call `DBSIZE` to get the number of keys `K`.

You will use `COUNT = K*RP/N`

For the first call, this is `COUNT = 200032*1/50 = 4000`.

For any other call, you need to calculate `RP = 1 - ReversedCursor/NextPowerOfTwo(K)`.

For example, let say you have done 20 calls already, so now `N = 30` (remaining number of calls). You called `DBSIZE` and got `K = 281569`. This means `NextPowerOfTwo(K) = 524288`, this is 2^19.

Your next cursor is 14509 in decimal = `000011100010101101` in binary. As the table size is 2^19, we represent it with 18 bits.

You reverse the bits and get `101101010001110000` in binary = 185456 in decimal. This means we have covered 185456 out of 524288. And:

```
RP = 1 - ReversedCursor/NextPowerOfTwo(K) = 1 - 185456 / 524288 = 0.65 or 65%
```

So you have to adjust:

```
COUNT = K*RP/N = 281569 * 0.65 / 30 = 6100
```

So in your next `SCAN` call you use `6100`. Makes sense it increased because:

- The amount of keys has increased from 200032 to 281569.
- Although we have only 60% of our initial estimate of calls remaining, progress is behind as 65% of the keyspace is pending to be scanned.

All this was assuming you are getting all keys. **If you're pattern-matching**, you need to use the past to estimate the remaining amount of keys to be found. We add as a factor `PM` (percent of matches) to the `COUNT` calculation.

```
COUNT = PM * K*RP/N

PM = keysFound / ( K * ReversedCursor/NextPowerOfTwo(K))
```

If after 20 calls, you have found only `keysFound = 2000` keys, then:

```
PM = 2000 / ( 281569 * 185456 / 524288) = 0.02
```

This means only 2% of the keys are matching our pattern so far, so

```
COUNT = PM * K*RP/N = 0.02 * 6100 = 122
```

This algorithm can probably be improved, but you get the idea.

Make sure to run some benchmarks on the `COUNT` number you'll use to start with, to measure how many milliseconds is your `SCAN` taking, as you may need to moderate your expectations about how many calls you need (`N`) to do this in a reasonable time without blocking the server, and adjust your `F` and `T` accordingly.

Comment: "As the table size is 2^19, we represent it with 18 bits." - shouldn't this be represented as 19 bits though? `Integer.toBinaryString(524288 - 1).length() = 19`